# google cloud console - phpmyadmin 404 not found

Tags: google-compute-engine

Trying to create a new instance for running a php web app. But never installed a new server before. So I have followed all the instructions from the link below but when I go to `http://[my ip addess]/phpmyadmin`

I get a 404 error.

`https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-lamp?_ga=2.212307860.-1468980495.1579877933`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Ubuntu Help Community, if you're getting a 404 error upon visiting http://localhost/phpmyadmin, you will need to configure apache2.conf to work with Phpmyadmin.

Try the following command:
$ gksudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Include the following line at the bottom of the file, save and quit.
$ Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

Greetings!